# Which Intel CPU? 3.3GHz x 6 or 4GHz x 4

Tags: processor, processor-architecture

I'm currently choosing parts for my new computer. I'm doing a lot of image processing and some of my algorithms are parallelized. In my free-time, I'm additionally up for some gaming.

My current system, although already built in 2011, runs an [Intel Core i7-2700K](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/61275/Intel-Core-i7-2700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) with 4 real cores (8 HT) and 3.50GHz base frequency. This guy still rocks and looking through today's CPU's kind of give me the feeling that physical limitations for faster machines are clearly visible.

After reading and looking through the prizes, I thought I found my favorite CPU for the next system, which is a [Intel Core i7-6700K 4GHz](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/88195/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz?_ga=1.233340126.1977817799.1443741286), but then I saw [this comparison](http://wccftech.com/intel-skylake-s-core-i7-6700-k-benchmarks/):

[image: compare]

Apparently, the [Intel Core i7-5820K with 6 cores](http://ark.intel.com/products/82932/Intel-Core-i7-5820K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) (which is the 5th and not the 6th generation) is in many tests faster. Important for me is of course, that the CPU supports DDR4 memory, which it does.

**Question:** Taking into account that the prize is the same for both processors, I would be glad if someone had a recommendation. I'm keen to hear whether the difference in architecture (Skylake-S vs. Haswell-E) is somehow important for me. Probably there are other things I haven't considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://www.bjorn3d.com/2015/08/intel-core-i7-6700k-review-skylake-falling/3/) could help you find your answer.

As you can see for photo editing the 6700k is pretty good but not the best

As you can see [here](http://techreport.com/review/28751/intel-core-i7-6700k-skylake-processor-reviewed/10), the 5960x does beat it quite often then not but it's also 3 times the price

So between the 6700k and 5820k
multicore: 5820k is about 25% faster.
singlecore the 6700k is 23% faster.
these are from benchmark scores

You cannot go wrong with either, noticeable advantages the 5820k has over 6700k is the memory bandwith which seriously quite high (Double actually) and the 2 cores (4threads)
So after reconsideration on my behalf, the 5820k might actually be the better choice since photo editing softwares are all 64bit and multicore nowdays. You can even overclock the 5820k more easily than the 6700k.
But then in gaming the 6700k takes the large, not by much but still noticable since it's single core performamce are pretty high. the 6700k is also power efficient and suports usb 3.1 natively (future proof)

5820k would be my choice, with a setup than doesn't bottleneck it's performances. Atleast for the next 4-5years you're good to go.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I guess I'm not willing to spend 1K+ Euro for the 5960X. On the other hand, for my purposes the 5820K wouldn't make much difference when I understood another page correctly. I will use only a single GPU and the PCIe lanes seem one difference (except the obvious 8core - 6core) between the 5960X and 5820.

Comment: Can you pull relevant bits of information from your links into this answer? If those links become broken, this answer loses a lot of value.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations! Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).

Comment: True, I never thought of that, I'll try to do my best.
thanks

Comment: @RudraMatroja After a lot of thinking, I guess the Haswell-E arch will be my choice like you suggested. I'll report back but I'm currently tending to give the 5960x a chance. I know it's very very expensive, but the performance is just incredible.

Comment: I know right. But be careful of the other parts prices too, the mobo to be precise, the socket is not cheap.

Comment: @Rudra I was thinking about an ASUS X99-A/U3.1. But I haven't decided yet for sure. I'm online in [chat] and I would welcome your opinion on this. Additionally, I was planning to put G.SKILL 64GB DDR4-2133 in it since the CPU only supports max 2133GHZ.